# Failed building wheel for chroma-hsnwlib , ( #include <Python.h> doesn't exist ) in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, langchain, large-language-model, chromadb

I am getting error "Failed building wheel for chroma-hsnwlib " in Ubuntu server.
In chronology :

1. /tmp/pip-build-env/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../detail/common.h: 226:10 : Python.h no such file or directory exist.  ( error originates from subprocess, likely not from pip )
2. Failed building wheel for chroma-hsnwlib
   created wheel for pypika  (->) stored in directory (->) successfully built pypika (->) Failed to build chroma-hsnwlib

any idea on how to solve this, or possible reason for the error.
This code works on my local computer but not on Ubuntu. Working on LLM based application using langchain. Requires Chromadb for that.

Comment: Have you installed the development headers for Python 3.10?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Yes, but can you give me the commands, i want to cross check

Comment: @Brian61354270 we have installed devtools , but still getting the same error